# NetSuite SuiteTalk API Request limits

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

Is there any documentations on the request limits of SuiteTalk? Or does anyone know?
I want to know if there are any limits on requests made on a per IP, per account, per X amount of time, or other?

Answer (score 1):

You can check your account’s concurrency limit at setup > integration > manage integrations. It should have a field called Account Concurrency Limit.

Lastly, the concurrency is only governed on a per user (if using user credentials to authenticate requests), per integration, and per account basis.

Answer (score 0):

You can search NetSuite's internal help documentation for "Web Services and RESTlet Concurrency Governance".  This will walk you through all of the factors that come into play regarding concurrency for Web Service (SOAP/Rest) and Restlet requests.

Comment: from what i can see, all limits are on the account and user. So there is no limits per IP. Would you know if that is true?